# Java: how to save the MouseButton status?

Tags: java, logging, mouse

So i'm writing a program that saves mouse button (currently just mousePressed, but will add mouseReleased once this will work) status to log file. How do i do that?
Current code:

```
import static com.sun.java.accessibility.util.AWTEventMonitor.addMouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class mouse {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
mouse();

} 
public static void mouse() throws InterruptedException{
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
        writeToFile(me);    //writeToFile saves the me value to txt
        } 
       });
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1); // time delay, so it saves every 1ms
}
}


public static void writeToFile(MouseEvent me){

try{
    String data =" "+me+" ";

    File file =new File("log.txt");

    //if log.txt doesn't exist, it makes it
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    //true = write
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(data);
        bufferWritter.close();


    }catch(IOException e){
    }
}

}
```

The program compiles and runs, but it doesn't do anything.
I thank you all in advance.

Comment: This is likely due to having the loop creating new listeners. Take a look at the mouseListener docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: nope, i tried putting for loop inside, so that it executes just `writeToFile(me);` line, but it still does nothing.

Comment: The listener should not have any loops, your GUI should wait and 'listen' for events. You will need a component in your GUI that will be the source for these events. For example, an object that encompasses the entire GUI that you can attach the listener to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not trying to create a GUI and instead want to log general Mouse position, then adding a MouseListener to your class will do nothing of use. Instead understand that Java is not optimized for this type of program, and you would likely have to use JNA or JNI to trap the OS's mouse handling code. If on the other hand you wish to trap the mouse usage of a Swing GUI, then you first need to create a Swing GUI and then add your MouseListener to it. I'd advise your reading the MouseListener Tutorial for more on this.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> Ultimately, it will be a part of GUI application, i'm just trying to make a concept of it.

Please understand that a MouseListener will not be functional without adding it to a Component that accepts one, that extends ultimately from the Component type, **and** that is displayed in a GUI. So in order to test your concept, you will again need to create a Swing GUI and add a MouseListener to one of the visualized components of your GUI. Again, please read the [MouseListener tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html).

---

> About overwriting the file, it doesn't, i took it from my previous program, and it works properly.

Sorry, my bad -- I misread your code.

---

**Edit 2**
And as noted in comment, the listener should not have loops, but rather should respond to mouse ***EVENTS***.  For example, the following code listens for mouse press, release, and drag and displays the information in a JTextArea. It would be trivial to change this to write to file:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleMouseListenerEg extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   private JPanel listenedToPanel = new JPanel();
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 25);

   public SimpleMouseListenerEg() {
      listenedToPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Listened To Panel"));
      MouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      listenedToPanel.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
      listenedToPanel.addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);

      textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(listenedToPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.EAST);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   // a combination MouseListener and MouseMotionListener
   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      private String template = "%-10s [%03d, %03d]%n";

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
         String text = String.format(template, "Pressed", mEvt.getX(), mEvt.getY());
         textArea.append(text);
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mEvt) {
         String text = String.format(template, "Released", mEvt.getX(), mEvt.getY());
         textArea.append(text);
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent mEvt) {
         String text = String.format(template, "Dragged", mEvt.getX(), mEvt.getY());
         textArea.append(text);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleMouseListenerEg mainPanel = new SimpleMouseListenerEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleMouseListenerEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Ultimately, it will be a part of GUI application, i'm just trying to make a concept of it. About overwriting the file, it doesn't, i took it from my previous program, and it works properly.

Comment: @dvd: please don't try to edit my answer as that's not very polite of you to do. I am curious as to why you wanted me to delete the first edit to my answer though.

Comment: I don't know man, I'm new to Stackoverflow... just tell me how to edit, and i will do it...

Comment: @dvd: how to edit what? You can edit your own question by pressing the edit link under it, but you shouldn't attempt to edit other's answers, least of all an answer to your own question. Later when you get more reputation, you'll be able to edit the questions and answers of others, but you still shouldn't do this to remove important information in the question or answer as that is called "defacing" an answer.

Comment: I misunderstood, my bad! Thank you for everything.